# ANSI Encoding validations

Tags: c#, c++

I have edit box which will accept the characters. Here I want to do tricky validation. I want to allow the user to enter the characters that are in ANSI range for the specific OS locale. 
For example

1. On English Windows version will it allow all English chars. No Chinese or Japanese.
2. On Japanese version it will allow English or Japanese. No Chinese.

Above behavior is observed in Notepad for ANSI encoding. On Japanese version it allows Japanese and English chars, won't allow Chinese characters. On English version didn't allow Japanese or Chinese chars.

So is there any way to validate the characters specific to ANSI encoding.

Comment: Do you need that in C# or C++? In C# you might want to take a look at the character classes (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedNamedBlocks)

Comment: There are no ANSI character encodings.  And Unicode doesn't distinguish between Japanese Kanji and Chinese characters.  So what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I am using C++. I was referring to ANSI encoding. As per my requirement ,If I am using English locale then my edit box should not allow Japanese or Chinese chars. But On Japanese local it should allow Japanese and English characters.

Comment: Why do you care what language/character set people are using? In other words, what are you trying to achieve ultimately?